# fileupload progress Bar misplacing primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-1.2

[image: Primeface form]

In the above picture, while uploading second file, it is showing progress bar for first fileupload

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText id="keyupload" value="Key file(extension should be .key)"/>
    <p:fileUpload id="keyfileUpload" label="Upload KeyFile" fileUploadListener="#{exampleBean.keyFileUpload}" mode="advanced" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(crt|key)$/" />
</h:panelGroup>

<p:separator id="separator1"/>

<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText id="certupload" value="Certificate and Key file(extension should be .crt)"/>
    <p:fileUpload id="crtUpload" label="Upload File" fileUploadListener="#{exampleBean.crtFileUpload}" mode="advanced" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(crt|key)$/" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

How to keep proper way, can anyone please help

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and state which version you are using.

Comment: Are you sure you are using JSF 1.2??

Comment: I did not downvote (yet) but please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive and also state your PF version